# A way of selecting the next xpath element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How can i switch to the next element from a table using python and selenium.
I have a website with a table that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYwKU.png
I managed to identify and click on the element from the first column.
Next, i want to select the element from second column which can have any value instead of "true".

I tried using Xpath Axes but i did not succed:

```
#find element 
find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 
'httpGzipActive')]")))
time.sleep(2)
find_elem.click()
time.sleep(2)

#here im trying to switch to the next element, which is Value column
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[* = 'data-cell-index']/following-sibling::data- 
cell-index").click()
```

To be applied to the following xhtml fragment (contents of the style attribute intentionally omitted):

```
<div data-cell-index="0" style="..."></div>
<div data-cell-index="0" style="...">httpGzipActive</div>
<div data-cell-index="1" style="..."></div>
<div data-cell-index="1" style="...">true</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath matches the sibling nodes carrying the `data-cell-index` attibute.

```
//div[@data-cell-index]/following-sibling::*[@data-cell-index]
```

Attributes are referenced by an `@` prefixed to their names. An axis like `following-sibling` asks for an element spec. Here it is the wildcard `*` but you could use `div` according to your fragment.

From your description you might actually want to change your code as follows:

```
find_elem.find_elements (By.XPATH, "./(following-sibling::*[@data-cell-index])[2]").click()
```

Your target node is not the immediate sibling successor carrying the `data-cell-index` attribute but the one after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable information.
I understand your proposal, seems what i need but i think there is still something im missing because i currently receive:

Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ./(following-sibling::*[@data-cell-index])[2] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './(following-sibling::*[@data-cell-index])[2]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I've checked the xpath expression with an [online xpath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) on the xml fragment wrapped into a valid standalone xml document as follows: `//div[contains(text(),  'httpGzipActive')]/./(following-sibling::*[@data-cell-index])[2]`.

Comment: I managed to make it work using:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='httpGzipActive']/following-sibling::div[@data-cell-index][2]").click()